# Какой вариант является правильным?

Tags: пунктуация

Звоню узнать: живы ли? 
Звоню узнать, живы ли?
Звоню узнать – живы ли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Абсолютно верно первое. Во втором не нужен вопросительный знак, т.к. предложение повествовательное сложноподчинённое. Третий вариант возможен, если хотите сделать предложение более экспрессивным, я лично экспрессии не вижу.